# What is favicon.ico and why does my server try to make a connection to it?

Tags: javascript, python, http, web

Im very new to web programming. I made a small front end program and decided to use python to host it on my computer. When I ran the python script I got the following messages on my terminal:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2019 15:40:45] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2019 15:40:45] "GET /style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2019 15:40:45] "GET /btnEvent.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2019 15:40:46] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

The first three files belong to my program so thats correct. However, theres a last file favicon.ico and the request apparently failed. Why did that happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Chrome searching for my favicon.ico when I serve up a file from ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003350/why-is-chrome-searching-for-my-favicon-ico-when-i-serve-up-a-file-from-asp-net-m)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A favicon.ico is the little icon that browsers display next to a page's title on a browser tab, or in the address bar next to its URL. In practical when you bookmark any page then it shows a logo of website which is nothing but `favicon.ico`. It is default lookup of browsers.