# Strange Castle Windsor Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor

I am getting an exception when initializing Castle Windsor in an ASP.NET MVC3 application.  Here is the exception that I am getting:

> Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException was unhandled
>   by user code   Message=Activation error occured while trying to get
>   instance of type IController, key "favicon.ico"
>   Source=Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation   StackTrace:
>          at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type
>   serviceType, String key) in
>   c:\Home\Chris\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:line
>   57
>          at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance[TService](String
>   key) in
>   c:\Home\Chris\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:line
>   103
>          at AN.Core.Windsor.Web.WindsorControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext
>   requestContext, String controllerName)   InnerException:
>   System.MissingMethodException
>          Message=Method not found: 'Castle.Core.Internal.GraphNode[] Castle.Core.Internal.GraphNode.get_Dependers()'.
>          Source=AN.Core.Windsor.Web
>          StackTrace:
>               at AN.Core.Windsor.Web.WindsorServiceLocator.DoGetInstance(Type
>   serviceType, String key)
>               at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type
>   serviceType, String key) in
>   c:\Home\Chris\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:line
>   49
>          InnerException:

Here is my initialization code in my global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    BootstrapWindsorContainer();
}

private static void BootstrapWindsorContainer()
{
    _container = new WindsorContainer()
        .Install(FromAssembly.InThisApplication());             

    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new WindsorServiceLocator(_container));

    var controllerFactory = new WindsorControllerFactory();
    ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
}
```

Comment: Is it just when initializing?  It looks like a reasonable error since the controller for the "favicon.ico" file will never be found.

Comment: It is weird.  If I comment out BootstrapWindsorContainer() then the page loads fine.

Comment: Do the answers in this question help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434900/why-is-my-castle-windsor-controller-factorys-getcontrollerinstance-being-call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a favicon.ico to the collection of routes to ignore.

For example:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico");
}
```