# Route rule for an image

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I am trying to create a route rule with for an image with a . in the name and it doesn't seem to be working for me.

```
routes.MapRoute(
     "Favicon", //Route Name
     "favicon.png",
     new { controller = "Content", action = "Images", id = "favicon.ico" }
);
```

The controller "Content" does not exist, I am trying to map to "Content/Images/favicon.ico" so  it picks up the images.  I have tried the route debugger and it looks like it is matching the right route but it is not showing the right image.

Any ideas?

Comment: This previous answer should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487230/serving-favicon-ico-in-asp-net-mvc