# How to add favicon on MVC view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, favicon, asp.net-mvc-partialview, shortcut

I was wondering how should I add `favicon` on `MVC` View?

Where do I need to add the code:

```
<link rel="icon" href="@Url.Content("~/content/favicon.ico")"/>
```

Comment: Had a look at this rather brand new post ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487230/serving-favicon-ico-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Yes, what I'am looking at is where should I add this code? I already added this under View but no joy :(

Answer (score -1):

Add it in layout view(inside head section)